# Setting OS Specific Keybindings - Cmd on Mac and Ctrl on Everything Else

Tags: javascript, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

When configuring [Ace](http://ace.c9.io) (the text editor), you can use OS specific keybindings, like `{win: "Ctrl-Esc", mac: "Cmd-Esc"}`. This shows that you can have OS specific keybindings in JavaScript, but how is it done?

I would like to create shortcuts that use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on OS X and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on other systems.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but straight from the Close/Flag reasons:  "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Comment: Close voters: please read the question carefully! He is **not** asking for recommendations. He would prefer a plain solution, but adds that a _comment_ recommending libraries would still be helpful.

Comment: @S.L.Barth - then it would be better to remove the blurb about comments suggesting libraries.  Otherwise, that's like saying, "I know recommendations are off-topic, so don't provide them as an answer, just as a comment, and everything's cool."  Doesn't jive.  Recommendations are off-topic as a reason, and trying to circumvent that is just going to raise eyebrows and cause the votes you're seeing here.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I don't think he's trying to circumvent the rules. But I agree that that blurb was better left out. Carl Smith, I could edit it out, but I'd prefer to leave the decision to you. If it were my question I'd remove the last sentence.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the feedback. I guess it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time there is no JavaScript API for detecting if the host OS uses the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key or the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key for keyboard shortcuts. The only way to determine this is to use platform sniffing.

This is usually done though the use of the [`navigator.platform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/platform) property. In fact, the library you mention, Ace editor, [actually does it this way](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/3b85ddfa051527f8feafd29a25f0fda9e95fc406/lib/ace/lib/useragent.js#L64). This property also has the advantage that it will not change if you change the user-agent string (at least not normally). On macOS, `navigator.platform` returns a string like `MacProcessor`, or `MacIntel` on an Intel-based Mac.

It's technically deprecated though (but not likely to be removed any time soon), and some browsers have implemented a newer [`navigator.userAgentData.platform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgentData) property in secure contexts only (takes the form of `macOS` on macOS).

With this knowledge, we can craft a regular expression that will match whichever property is available. Something like the following should be safe and future-proof.

```
/mac/i.test(navigator.userAgentData ? navigator.userAgentData.platform : navigator.platform);
```

Now we just need to use the boolean return value from this statement, to determine if our shortcut key should be [`e.metaKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey), or [`e.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey).

## Working Example:

```js
var isMac = /mac/i.test(navigator.userAgentData ? navigator.userAgentData.platform : navigator.platform);

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 67 && (isMac ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
        document.getElementById('textarea').value += 'Thanks ' + (isMac ? 'Mac' : 'Non-Mac') + '!\n';
    }
});
```

```html
<p>Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on Mac, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on everything else.</p>

<textarea id="textarea" style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" placeholder="Click me then use shortcut keys."></textarea>
```

## Alternately:

You might also consider just allowing the user to use either shortcut on any platform.

## Working Example:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey)) {
        document.getElementById('textarea').value += 'Thanks!\n';
    }
});
```

```html
<p>Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.</p>

<textarea id="textarea" style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" placeholder="Click me then use shortcut keys."></textarea>
```